# Jquery .show() not revealing a div with visibility of hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basic jQuery question:

I am trying to reveal a `div` that has been marked as hidden using jQuery. But am not quite getting it

I've created a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/VwjxJ/

Basically, I want to use `style="visibility: hidden;"` rather than `style="display: none;"` as I want the space of the hidden element to be maintained

Have tried using [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show), [`fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn) etc but neither work (they do for `style="display: none;"`)

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try changing the framework on your jsfiddle to jQuery.

Comment: @a'r: **The problem still remains**. Here is a corrected version: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/9Z6nt/19/

Comment: In your example you didn't set up the right library for your project, in the "choose framework" you should choose "jQuery".

Comment: Have a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/9Z6nt/19/

Comment: sorry - made a mess of that JSFiddle - now corrected - have updated the URL in the question.

Comment: yes - I have corrected that now http://jsfiddle.net/VwjxJ/

Comment: +1 to counter the downvotes.... people should spend more time trying to understand the problem...

Comment: downvotes are presumably for messing up the JSFiddle?

Comment: I think it was because other people thought you just forgot to select the right library (and after changing it, it seemed to worked). But they didn't read your question and the code carefully. Why else would the first comment get 5 upvotes? Yes, maybe your jsfiddle was not correct, but that is no reason for downvotes imo. The problem was clear even without that (and it was easy to fix).

Comment: +1 to counter premature downvotes also, agree with felix.

Comment: thanks @Felix Kling & jammypeach

Answer (score 129, accepted):

If you have hidden it with `visibility:hidden` then you can show it with jQuery by

```
$(".Deposit").css('visibility', 'visible');
```

And in the fiddle you are missing jQuery. **Here is a demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/9Z6nt/20/

Comment: `document.ready` is not necessary. The code is run `onLoad` (selectbox above the frameworks).

Comment: Oh, didn't notice that, thanks. But will be helpful in real code if JS is called before DOM being ready.

Comment: @Imray It does. Its not for the solution of `visibility:hidden`, I only fixed his one.

Answer (score 12):

According to JQuery documentation `.show()` "is roughly equivalent to calling `.css('display', 'block')`, except that the display property is restored to whatever it was initially."
Set the style explicitly instead. You could use a CSS class

```
.hidden{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.shown{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

and set is using

```
$("#yourdiv").removeClass("hidden").addClass("shown");
```

Comment: `$("#yourdiv").toggleClass('hidden')` ; no need for the "shown" class

Comment: It's not exactly the same. It depends on possible more general overrides in other parts of the CSS, but usually you would probably get away with that, yes.

Answer (score 8):

If you want the space of the hidden element to be maintained, use opacity.

i.e:

```
$('div').fadeTo(500,1) //show
$('div').fadeTo(500,0) //hide
```

for example:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style='opacity:0'>
  Test opacity
</div>


<button onclick="$('div').fadeTo(500,1);">Show</button>
<button onclick="$('div').fadeTo(500,0);">Hide</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Hey man your fiddle is working just choose framework jQuery on the fiddle.
If its visibility hidden then change the css visibility property to visible.

`(".Deposit").css('visibility','visible');`

Answer (score 2):

here we go :)

```
$(".Deposit").show();

    $(".Deposit").fadeOut(500,function(){
        $(this).css({"display":"block","visibility":"hidden"});

    });
```

Comment: yeah, that's the ticket!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".Deposit").show();

$(".Deposit").fadeTo(500,0);
```