# How to display hidden div using jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

I'd like to display a hidden div using jquery.  For some reason, show() isn't working in my example.  If I remove the hidden attribute and use hide(), that does work.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
<div id="mydiv" style="visibility:hidden">some text</div>
<button onclick="$('#mydiv').show();">click me</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5pmLw8r2/

Comment: `show()` and `hide()` modify the `display` property. You could change your `div` to use `display:none` instead?

Comment: use display:none instead of visibility:hidden to use .show()

Comment: [this has been answered already](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204494/jquery-show-not-revealing-a-div-with-visibility-of-hidden)

Answer (score 2):

try using display:none instead of visibility:hidden

the .show and .hide() toggle display attribute not visibility

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the CSS instead:

```
<button onclick="$('#mydiv').css('visibility', 'visible');">click me</button>
```

If you want to use `hide()` and `show()` you can instead use the `display` attribute:

```
<div id="mydiv" style="display: none;">some text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="mydiv" style="visibility:hidden">some text</div>
<button onclick="$('#mydiv').css('visibility', 'visible');">click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a css function:

```
$('#mydiv').css('visibility', 'visible');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/iam_groot/Loyvpm1y/

Or just use a display poperty:

```
<div id="mydiv" style="display:none;">some text</div>
<button onclick="$('#mydiv').show();">click me</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/iam_groot/gfeovoby/1