# Show icon only if sub menu exists

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

in my tablet navigation there are some 'plus' icons to toggle the sub menu. I want to display the plus icon only if the sub menu exists.

i already tried it with this code:

```
        if($('.tablet-li-item').find('.tablet-sub-menu').length !== 0) {
        $(this).children('.open-btn').css('display', 'block');
    }
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="tablet-nav">
        {% for menuItem in menu.menuStructure %}
            <li class="tablet-li-item">
                {{ render( controller( "ez_content:viewLocation", {"locationId": menuItem.location.id, "viewType": "menu"} ) ) }}
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down open-btn" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <div class="arrow"></div>
                {% if menuItem.submenu|length > 0 %}
                    <ul class="tablet-sub-menu" hidden>
                        <div class="inner-tablet-sub-menu">
                        {% for submenu in menuItem.submenu %}
                            <li class="tablet-sub-li-item">
                                {{ render( controller( "ez_content:viewLocation", {"locationId": submenu.location.id, "viewType": "menu"} ) ) }}
                            </li>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    </ul>
                {% endif %}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
```

this solution only works if i hover/click the object, unfortunately this solution isn't right in this situation, because it's a tablet menu.

Maybe somebody can help me with this problem.

**EDIT:**

Now i got it, i tried it with the jquery functions `has()` and `addClass()`

```
$('.tablet-li-item').has('ul').children('.open-btn').addClass('active');
```

instead of `addClass()`, `show()` would also be a possible solution.

Comment: What is the scope of $(this). We need more of your code to help you out here. Please paste your html setup as well.

Comment: I added the html

Comment: Thanks. But there is still no scope for $(this) in your edit. Your if-statement, does not put jQuery in a scope, where this points to anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess here is that your fault lies within `$(this)` which is out of a scope.

You can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tablet-li-item').each(function(){
        if( $(this).find('.tablet-sub-menu').length > 0 ){
            $(this).children('.open-btn').css('visibility', 'visible');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, unfortunately the buttons doesn't show up, i really don't know why^^

Comment: Have you inspected the elements to see if there is any css preventing them from displaying?

Comment: Yes i have, default value of 'open-btn' is 'visibility: hidden', this should be overwritten by the jquery function, but it doesn't

Comment: Well, that explains it. Setting display: block, as long as they have visibility:hidden won't do anything. Visibility then needs to be set to visibility: visible. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204494/jquery-show-not-revealing-a-div-with-visibility-of-hidden

Comment: Yes now I get it too. Thanks for your help! :D